# Replacing cell content Jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I replace the cell content where a link sits inside and it has been clicked on?

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td>link here</td>
   <td>link here</td>
   <td>link here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

For example clicking the link in the second cell should replace the second cell content with `test` third link replaces third cell and so on. Basically replace the cell content of which the link sits in.

Comment: I recommend taking an hour or two to read through [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It really only takes that long, and gives you a very solid understanding of how to do basic things like this, saving you a huge amount of time.

Comment: There are also good books on it.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder I will do that, I'm just getting into it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$('table').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('td').html('test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
$("td").click(function() {
    $(this).text("test");
});
```

Comment: OP wants to click on the link. What if there is other content in the td?

Answer (score 0):

You must assign the jQuery click event to every cell:

```
$(document).ready(function {
    $("td").click(function() {
        $(this).html("test"); // Change the clicked cell content for test
    });
});
```

Comment: Better to create the event on the table. That way you have one event listener instead of potentially 100s or even more.

Comment: *"You must assign the jQuery click event to every cell"* No, you mustn't, much better to use event delegation.